# melting ic epoxy casing

Tags: integrated-circuit, soldering, damage

I was attempting to remove solder with faulty solder braid (there was no flux in the section I was using (for some reason...)), and I kept the soldering Iron on it for far longer healthy. Now the package has reflective spots on it which I would guess were caused by melting. Does anybody have experience with this, or have any guesses as to if it should still work? (It isn't very testable in it's current configuration)

Comment: if you can solder it, you can test it.

Answer (score 1):

They're probably just flux. Epoxy doesn't melt, it chars.

It is a thermoset polymer that cures in an irreversible polymerization process.

Comment: Turns out it did break. I couldn't get a good picture of it, but to add some more detail sections of the package became reflective instead of the standard mat black.